# Using in-built sql "Convert" function in nhibernate criteria

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, nhibernate-projections

I want to make use of the Convert function in SQL Server 2008 so I can search on a DateTime column.

The proposed SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT (list of fields) FROM aTable
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), theColumn) LIKE '%2009%'
```

Here is part of the criteria that tries to emulate the call to convert:

```
Projections.SqlFunction("CONVERT", 
  NHibernateUtil.String, 
  Projections.Constant("varchar(25)"), 
  Projections.Property(searchCol))
```

The search column would be dynamically selected so it cannot be hard coded in a query.

The problem is that when the SQL is generated by nhibernate, its passing in the data type as a string, when there shouldn't be any quotes around it.

So the generated sql looks like:

```
(convert(@p3, this_.theColumn) LIKE @p4
```

When it needs to be:

```
(convert(varchar(25), this_.theColumn) LIKE @p4
```

I am definitely sure the problem is with `Projections.Constant("varchar(25)")` but I do not know the correct projections syntax to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could accept the `CAST` instead of `CONVERT` *(And I am almost sure that you can)*, then there is more straightforward solution.

Instead of calling *"SQL Server related"* function, let's call the abstraction, which should be working on most DB Servers *(based on supported NHibernate dilacts)*

```
Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property(searchCol))
```

So the `Restriction` used in a `WHERE` clause could look like this:

```
Restrictions
    .Like (
        Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property(searchCol))
        , "2009"
        , MatchMode.Anywhere
    )
```

And the result generated by NHibernate, using the SQL Server dialect would be:

```
WHERE cast( this_.theColumn as NVARCHAR(255)) like @p1 ... @p1=N'%2009%'
```

Comment: Yeah I found Cast as an alternative to Convert and it seems to work, thanks.

Comment: Any way to do same with LINQ to NH? Please please!!